# Extending View class and layouts in Android

Tags: android, layout, android-custom-view

I am playing with layouts and views in Android. My layout looks like:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <com.mycode.MyView
            android:id="@+id/MyView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/leftpane"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.95"
            android:background="@color/leftpane_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay" >

        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

If i comment the lines `<com.mycode.MyView .... />`, the left linear layout (with id leftpane) is showed, otherwise not. If i add another layout after the leftpane layout (for example a scroll view layout), it does not get showed as well.
Why using my custom view (MyView) makes disappear all other layouts?
What i would like to do is to have my custom View for the background of the application, where i would show images, and some other view over the background, like scroll views, buttons and so on.
This is the code of MyView class. Keep in mind that i need to draw on the background of the activity an images (on the whole background, obviously not including the action bar):

```
/**
*/
class   MyView extends View
{
    TextPaint   text_paint;
    Paint       paint;

    private void    InitView()
    {
        text_paint = new TextPaint( Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG );
        text_paint.setColor( Color.BLACK );
        paint = new Paint();
    }

    public MyView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        InitView();
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        InitView();
    }


    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defaultStyle)
    {   
        super(context, attrs, defaultStyle);
        InitView();
    }


    @Override
    protected void  onDraw( Canvas canvas )
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        //int   w, h;
        //w = canvas.getWidth();
        //h = canvas.getHeight();
        //paint.setColor( Color.WHITE );
        //canvas.drawRect(0, 0, w-1, h-1, paint );
        //canvas.drawText( "ciao", 100, 100, text_paint);
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your view's height as:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: It is really an empty implementation: i just call the onDraw() method of the super class. Nothing else.

Comment: Try to change your view to a EditText or any order standard widget.

Comment: I changed it. If i use fill_parent, i see one big edit text view and nothing other. If i use wrap_content, the edit text is smaller in height and i can see the other layouts on the screen. I need a way to draw on the background of the app an image (that can change with time) but still have the layouts (buttons, scroll view etc..) showed over the background.

Comment: To set background of the activity (you meant the app), you just need to set the first linearlayout "android:background=@drawable/some_imge".

Comment: Yes, but the user can change the image. Furthermore, i want to implement a pinch-to-zoom feature, so i think i need a custom view to handle background rendering.

Comment: You can programmatically change layout's background, so user can change the image. But if you want pinch-to-zoom, you have to custom a view.

Comment: If you view is used to show background of the activity, then I think you may use FrameLayout instead of LinearLayout.

Comment: @MarcoMasci maybe you should use FrameLayout or merge replace the root LinearLayout

Comment: It worked with FrameLayout. I am going to read something about FrameLayout and the difference with the LinearLayout. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you did some error work when you overrode the onMeasure method in your custom MyView,
and so the MyView's match all the parent view.
Can you show your code which in the onLayout and onMeasure method of the MyView.